# Propagating loniceras for beginners

Tags: propagation, climbers, honeysuckle

A neighbor of mine have a beautiful lonicera plant that just flowered - this may be the third time this year! He offered to me to take as many cuttings as I wish, and says that I just need to put them in water (like indoor flowers), and they will root - and later on such cuttings may be moved to soil, and become real plants. Is that true?

What would be the right way to use my neighbor's generous offer?

I just have to have that plant, I almost fainted when I sensed fragrance of their flowers this morning! :)

I do not have any experience at propagating plants using cuttings, and probably have brown thumb for such work.

*EDIT: Meanwhile, I discovered [a series of blog posts](https://lifewithkali.wordpress.com/tag/honeysuckle-2/) describing 43-day experiment of rooting lonicera in water.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah smells great that flower!

I never propagated this plant, but according to '[the web](http://homeguides.sfgate.com/honeysuckle-root-water-58206.html)' cuttings will root easily, and putting them in just water seems successful.

Good luck.